# expl3: How to make some keys required?

Tags: errors, expl3, latex3, l3keys

I have discovered the l3keys package and would like to use it. Here, specifically, I want to enforce that some keys are required. According to the documentation, the property "value_required:n" could be used for this:

> `⟨key⟩ .value_required:n = true|false`: Specifies that ⟨key⟩ must receive a ⟨value⟩ when used. If a ⟨value⟩ is not given then an error will be issued. Setting the property “false” cancels the restriction.

If I understand correctly, `\mycommand{}` should raise an error in the below example, because option `key` is not provided. However, why is this not the case?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mykeys/key }
 { 
  key .tl_set:N = \l__mykeys_key_tl,
  key .value_required:n = true
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}
{
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { mykeys/key } { #1 }
  Key~1~value:~\l__mykeys_key_tl
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% This works as expected.
\mycommand{key=value}

% Here I expect an error, but there is none
\mycommand{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: no it means you must give a value if it is used so you can not do `\mycommand{key}`

Comment: to ensure it is used just pre-define `\l__mykeys_key_tl` to give a error, and use it  somewhere after `\keys_set:nn `

Comment: Ah, bummer. Failed to read the quoted text carefully enough. I'm having trouble understanding the second comment, though. Is it possible to force that a key is mandatory?

Comment: As I say only I think by intialising it (with a macro def or `.initial` key property) to an error so you have to set it, but the error is then when the code uses it, not while parsing keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.value_required:n = true` means that when you supply the key, a value must be provided.

You can initialize the value to something distinguishable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { mykeys/key }
 { 
  key .tl_set:N = \l__mykeys_key_tl,
  key .initial:n = \q_nil,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}
{
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { mykeys/key } { #1 }
  \quark_if_nil:VTF \l__mykeys_key_tl
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { mykeys } { missing } { key }
   }
   {
    Key~1~value:~\l__mykeys_key_tl
   }
  \group_end:
}

\msg_new:nnnn { mykeys } { missing }
 { Key~'#1'~not~set }
 { You~must~set~the~key~'#1'}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% This works as expected.
\mycommand{key=value}

% Here I expect an error, but there is none
\mycommand{}

\end{document}
```

Console output

```
! Package mykeys Error: Key 'key' not set

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.38 \mycommand{}

? h

You must set the key 'key'

?
```

Comment: That's clean because explicit. Thanks. Alternatively, initializing `key` with `key .initial:n = {\msg_error:nnn { mykeys } { missing } { key }}`, as suggested above in the comments, can be useful as well.

Comment: @normanius With my approach, the command does nothing except issuing  the error message. With yours, things can be more complex as regards error recovery.